# How to get symbolic name of WinAPI error?

Tags: windows, winapi, error-handling

I'm interested in obtaining symbolic name (**not** the text description!) for WinAPI error code (e.g. ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED for error code 5). Is there any way to do this without implementing a custom error table in my code?

Answer (score 4):

There is no API to do this. You will need to look the value up from a table. You could generate the table by parsing `winerror.h`.

Answer (score 1):

As said before there is no way of getting the symbolic name of an error code.

But there is a way of getting a description of an error code. This is a small function that I use to get more information about an error without looking it up:

```
void printLastError(DWORD errCode)
{
   LPVOID lpMsgBuff;
   int len;

   len = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                       NULL,
                       errCode,
                       MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                       (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuff,
                       0,
                       NULL);
   if (len > 0)
   {
      printf("error %d: %s\n", errCode, lpMsgBuff);
      LocalFree(lpMsgBuff);   // release allocated memory!!!
   }
}
```